# Set javax.net.ssl.trustStore from inside an Axis2 web service

Tags: web-services, ssl, wso2, apache-axis, truststore

I coded a web service A which call another web service B located in https://servername:9443/services/AuthenticationAdmin.
To validate the server certificate I set the truststore:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/home/wso2/wso2/bin/wso2bam-2.5.0/repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "wso2carbon");
```

As you can see I've tried to reference the truststore located in the filesystem of the host where my web service A is deployed. But when the web service B is invoked (from ny web service A) I receive the following error:

```
<soapenv:Reason xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US">Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty</soapenv:Text>
</soapenv:Reason>
```

Afterwards I've tried to put the truststore file inside the .aar file and I referenced it as follow:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/wso2carbon.jks");
```

and even

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "wso2carbon.jks");
```

but no success.

How can I set the truststore from inside an Axis2 web service?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This means the path is not correct or the wso2carbon.jks file does not have read permission.

You can find a sample on how trustStore is set in [1]. See class ServiceInvoker

[1] - http://hi-my-world.blogspot.com/2014/04/how-to-write-client-to-invoke-wso2.html

Comment: I've checked it and it exists and has read permissions: `wso2@BD-VM-D-WSO2BAM:~$ ls -l /home/wso2/wso2/bin/wso2bam-2.5.0/repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks`
`-rw-r--r-- 1 wso2 wso2 33260 Sep  4  2013 /home/wso2/wso2/bin/wso2bam-2.5.0/repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks`